# Passay с несколькими языками

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

Использую бибилиотеку passay, для проверки паролей в веб-проекте на spring boot. Как добавить кастомный файл с локализацией разобрался. 
Вопрос, можно ли для этой библиотеки использовать несколько файлов локализации в зависимости от используемой языковой локали на веб-страницах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил путем проверки текущей локали и выбора соответствующего кастомного файла локализации для passay